# Como abrir diferentes rdlc em um único controle Report Viewer?

Tags: vb.net, reportviewer, visual-studio-2015

O que pode estar errado no meu código abaixo?

```
Private Sub LocalReport(ByVal digito As Integer)

Dim relatorioCorrente = New Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportDataSource()

ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear()
If (digito = 1) Then
    ReportViewer1.LocalReport.ReportEmbeddedResource = "ReportViewer.rpt1.rdlc"
    mcv_modbusTableAdapter.Fill(geradorxmlDS.mcv_modbus)
    relatorioCorrente.Name = "geradorxmlDS"
    relatorioCorrente.Value = mcv_malhaBindingSource
    ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(relatorioCorrente)
ElseIf (digito = 2) Then
    ReportViewer1.LocalReport.ReportEmbeddedResource = "ReportViewer.rpt2.rdlc"
    mcv_modbusTableAdapter.Fill(geradorxmlDS.mcv_modbus)
    relatorioCorrente.Name = "geradorxmlDS"
    relatorioCorrente.Value = mcv_modbusBindingSource
    ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(relatorioCorrente)
ElseIf (digito = 3) Then
    ReportViewer1.LocalReport.ReportEmbeddedResource = "ReportViewer.rpt3.rdlc"
    mcv_registroTableAdapter.Fill(geradorxmlDS.mcv_registro)
    relatorioCorrente.Name = "geradorxmlDS"
    relatorioCorrente.Value = mcv_registroBindingSource
    ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(relatorioCorrente)
End If
ReportViewer1.RefreshReport()
```

End Sub

Será que alguém poderia dar alguma sugestão? Obrigado desde já pela ajuda fornecida.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Meu problema já foi resolvido. Segue solução abaixo para consulta no futuro.

```
    Public Class frmReport
```

Dim codRPT As Integer

Private Sub LocalReport(ByVal digito As Integer)

Dim relatorioCorrente = New Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportDataSource()

If (digito = 1) Then
mcv_malhaTableAdapter.Fill(geradorxmlDS.mcv_malha)
relatorioCorrente.Name = “malhDS”
relatorioCorrente.Value = geradorxmlDS.mcv_malha
RV.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear()
RV.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(relatorioCorrente)
RV.LocalReport.ReportEmbeddedResource = “ReportViewer.rpt1.rdlc”
ElseIf (digito = 2) Then
mcv_modbusTableAdapter.Fill(geradorxmlDS.mcv_modbus)
relatorioCorrente.Name = “modbDS”
relatorioCorrente.Value = geradorxmlDS.mcv_modbus
RV.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear()
RV.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(relatorioCorrente)
RV.LocalReport.ReportEmbeddedResource = “ReportViewer.rpt2.rdlc”
ElseIf (digito = 3) Then
mcv_registroTableAdapter.Fill(geradorxmlDS.mcv_registro)
relatorioCorrente.Name = “regiDS”
relatorioCorrente.Value = geradorxmlDS.mcv_registro
RV.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear()
RV.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(relatorioCorrente)
RV.LocalReport.ReportEmbeddedResource = “ReportViewer.rpt3.rdlc”
End If
RV.RefreshReport()

End Sub

Private Sub ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged_1(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged

LocalReport(ComboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString)

End Sub

End Class

Comment: Formata o código, ta horrível assim